# Android выборка данных из двух разных таблиц и выдача в ListView

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, sqlite, listview

Писал задачник-ежедневник на Android. Есть БД с такой структурой:

```
  Задачи с датами             Повторяющиеся задачи
    | ID | Имя           |      | ID | Имя         |
    |----|---------------|      |----|-------------|
    | 1  | Id            |      | 1  |id           |
    | 2  | дата выполн.  |      | 2  | тип повтора | //например "каждую неделю"
    | 3  | время         |      | 3  | Знач.повтора| //Среда
    | 4  | Текст задачи  |      | 4  | Время       |
                                | 5  | Текст задачи|
```

1) Как составить SQL-запрос для выборки данных из этих таблиц, причем сортировать по времени, вне зависимости из какой таблицы взяли значение.

2) Запихнуть все в ListView.

Как это сделать?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В данном случае не вижу смысла разделять сущности по таблицам. Они спокойно уместся и в одной. И тогда никаких проблем у вас не возникнет с сортировкой, выборкой и т.д.

Comment: Тоесть если задача "С датой" - поля "Тип повтора" и "Знач. повтора" остаются пустыми, 
а если "повторяющаяся" - то поле "Дата выполнения" оставляем пустым?

Comment: тип повтора просто придумайте типа `NONE` (никакой) для задач без повтора. А вообще, если влом переделывать, гуглите на тему `JOIN`, `SQLITE` его вроде поддерживает

Comment: @Алексей ну да, суть вы уловили. Не рекомендую лепить горбатого, не поленитесь и переделайте бд.

Answer (score 1):

Для присоединения дополнительных таблиц в sqlite предусмотрено ключевое слово JOIN. Почитайте об этом, очень полезная штука. Но в вашем случае, как уже было сказано в комментариях, лучше хранить данные в одной таблице.